# How to find the total money of parent node of tree and number of pair under particular parent according to a particular pattern 1:2or2:1,1:1

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am working on a project in which members are added in a tree pattern, and get the payment accordingly.

My tbltestingtree structure is as follow:

```
        Id         ParentId        IsLeft           IsRight
         1          Null             Null             Null
         2           1                1               Null
         3           1               Null               1
         4           2                1               Null
         5           2               Null               1
         6           3                1               Null
         7           3               Null               1
         8           4                1               Null
         9           4               Null               1
         10          5                1               Null
```

Initially 1500$ are given to parent when two nodes are added to its left and one to his right(2:1) . and then 500$ for each pair.

My problem is to find the query which can return the total income of any given  node.

[image]

According to figure node 1 must get 2500$ (1500+500+500) first 500$ is for node 4 and second 500$ is for node 3.

According to figure node 2 must get 1500$ because it has two nodes to its left and one node to its right this means a ratio of (2:1). and has  no pairs

According to figure node 3 must get 0$ because it does not have any nodes in ratio(2:1)

one thing has to be kept in mind that 1500$ will be the first payment and then only the other pairs will be counted, and 1500$ will be given when node has ratio 2:1(two nodes on left and one on right) but no money when ratio is 1:2(one node on left and two on right)

I have found the query which will count all the pairs below a particular node and give receiving amount according to 500$,  but the query has not been able to consider the first condition that is the 2:1 condition

```
        declare @ParentId as int
         set @ParentId=1

       create table #temp_table_name
        (
          ParentId varchar(30) null,
         )


      ;with Child as
       (
    select id,ParentId from tblTestingTree where id=@ParentId
    union all
    Select tblTestingTree.Id,tblTestingTree.parentId from tblTestingTree 
    inner join Child 
    on tblTestingTree.ParentId=Child.Id
       )

  insert into #temp_table_name
  select c.ParentId  from tblTestingTree T join Child c
  on c.Id=t.Id
  WHERE ISNULL(T.ParentId, 0) <> 0 and c.ParentId!=@ParentId
  group by c.ParentId
  having COUNT(c.ParentId)>1 

  select COUNT(*)*500 as totalmoney from #temp_table_name

  drop table #temp_table_name
```

Answer (score 0):

As you need to get the sum for particular node, you can do it in this way:

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
     [ID] TINYINT
    ,[ParentID] TINYINT
    ,[IsLeft] TINYINT
    ,[IsRight] TINYINT
)

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([ID], [ParentID], [IsLeft], [IsRight])
VALUES   (1,NULL,NULL,NULL)
        ,(2,1,1,NULL)
        ,(3,1,NULL,1)
        ,(4,2,1,NULL)
        ,(5,2,NULL,1)
        ,(6,3,1,NULL)
        ,(7,3,NULL,1)
        ,(8,4,1,NULL)
        ,(9,4,NULL,1)
        ,(10,5,1,NULL)

DECLARE @ParentID TINYINT = 1
DECLARE @ParentSUM SMALLINT = 0


DECLARE @SubLeftID TINYINT
DECLARE @SubRightID TINYINT

SELECT @SubLeftID = CASE WHEN [IsLeft] = 1 THEN [ID] ELSE @SubLeftID END
      ,@SubRightID = CASE WHEN [IsRight] = 1 THEN [ID] ELSE @SubRightID END
FROM @DataSource
WHERE ParentID = @ParentID

/*
SELECT @SubLeftID = IIF([IsLeft] = 1, [ID], @SubLeftID)
      ,@SubRightID = IIF([IsRight] = 1, [ID], @SubRightID)
FROM @DataSource
WHERE ParentID = @ParentID
*/

IF @SubLeftID IS NOT NULL AND @SubRightID IS NOT NULL AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM @DataSource WHERE [IsLeft] = 1 AND ParentID = @SubLeftID)
BEGIN

    SET @ParentSUM = 1500

    ;WITH DataSource AS
    (

        SELECT [ID], [ParentID], [IsLeft], [IsRight], 0 AS [Level] 
        FROM @DataSource
        WHERE [ParentID] = @ParentID
        UNION ALL
        SELECT RecursiveMember.[ID], RecursiveMember.[ParentID], RecursiveMember.[IsLeft], RecursiveMember.[IsRight], Level + 1 
        FROM @DataSource RecursiveMember
        INNER JOIN DataSource AnchorMember
            ON RecursiveMember.[ParentID] = AnchorMember.[ID]
    )
    SELECT @ParentSUM = @ParentSUM + COUNT([ParentID]) * 500
    FROM
    (
        SELECT [ParentID]
              ,'IsLeft' AS [Direction]
              ,1 AS [Value]
        FROM DataSource
        WHERE [IsLeft] = 1
            AND [ID] <> @ParentID --AND [ID] NOT IN (@SubLeftID, @ParentID)
            AND [ParentID] NOT IN (@ParentID, @SubLeftID)
        UNION ALL
        SELECT [ParentID]
              ,'IsRight' AS [Direction]
              ,1 AS [Value]
        FROM DataSource
        WHERE [IsRight] = 1
            AND [ParentID] <> @ParentID
    ) AS DataSource
    PIVOT
    (
        MAX([Value]) FOR [Direction] IN ([IsLeft], [IsRight])
    ) PVT
    WHERE [IsLeft] IS NOT NULL AND [IsRight] IS NOT NULL

END

SELECT @ParentSUM
```

What I am doing is:

- check if the given node has right sub node and left sub node which has left sub node itself (if so add 1500)
- if the before condition is true, count  how many sub pairs exists for the specified node excluding the its sub pair, and the sub pair of its left sub node

Comment: thanks for your suggestion  but what will we the output of above code please mention

Comment: It is full working exmaple, just copy it and executed it. Change the  `@ParentID` to 2 and 3 to see that it will return what you need. It is not suggestion, it is solution. Just test it.

Comment: when we execute this code it will show the following error          "Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 28
Incorrect syntax near '='."

Comment: Check out the example here - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/12155. Just change the play with the `@ParentID` and the sample data.

Comment: what you mean by IIF here

Comment: This is just an alternative syntax of `CASE WHEN` block - check this http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213574.aspx and I guess you were able to run the example?

Comment: when we run code which is provide by you on sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/12155. is run fine  but when we copy the code from this link and run on my sql server 2008  it give the following error      IIF is not a recognized built-in function ,incorrect syntax near '='

Comment: @user2342574 This is because the `IIF` function is available in the SQL Server 2012, I will edit the answer and replace it with `CASE WHEN` block. Check the edited answer now and tell is everything ok now?

Comment: thanks  it works fine for me but if we want to count total number of pair in 2:1 or 1:2 ratio for first pair after that 1:1 ratio how it can be done please suggest us

Comment: In the solution above you are counting the 2:1 ratio, so it is easy to   make it work with 1:2 ratio, too. I do not know your logic, but this could be placed in function or procedure that except the ratio as parameter and the node id.

Comment: how please provide the solution

Comment: @user2342574 I have already provided to you the solution. You just try to understand how it is working and it will be easy to write the code for the other cases (especially the 1:2) ratio.

Comment: @user2342574 Imagine you have a store procedure or scalar function with two input parameters. The first one is the `nodeid` for which you need to calculated the sum. The second one is `mode` - it is string and can be `2:1`, `1:2` or `1:1`. Then in the procedure/function you have three cases (for each mode) divided with `IF` statements. If `mode` is `2:1` use the code above, if the `mode` is `1:2` use the other calculations.

Comment: please provide full stored procedure code of above code so that i calculate all the pair in 2:1,1:2 or 1:1 ratio of particular node

Comment: please provide full stored procedure code for  count total number of pairs in 2:1 ratio or 1:2 ( 2 left nodes and 1 right node for a given node or 1 left node and 2 right node for a given node )ratio for first payment  and after that in 1:1 ratio means 1 left and 1 right node for a given node for all other payment.
and
if new user join first from left then pair counting start from left ,if new user join first from right then pair counting start from left.

Comment: please provide full stored procedure code for count total number of pairs in 2:1 ratio or 1:2 ( 2 left nodes and 1 right node for a given node or 1 left node and 2 right node for a given node )ratio for first payment and after that in 1:1 ratio means 1 left and 1 right node for a given node for all other payment. and if new user join first from left then pair counting start from left ,if new user join first from right then pair counting start from left.                                                               Please sir provide stored procedure its urgent for me               thanks

Comment: please provide full stored procedure code for count total number of pairs in 2:1 ratio or 1:2 ( 2 left nodes and 1 right node for a given node or 1 left node and 2 right node for a given node )ratio for first payment and after that in 1:1 ratio means 1 left and 1 right node for a given node for all other payment. and if new user join first from left then pair counting start from left ,if new user join first from right then pair counting start from left. Please sir provide stored procedure its urgent for me thanks –

Comment: @user2342574 This was almost a month ago, why just don't you understand the code and do it yourself?

Comment: how we can check whether the joining is start firstly from left side or right side and then  how we can perform counting on the base of firstly joying side(left side or right side) in 1:2 or 2:1,1:1 ratio

Comment: You should create a stored procedure or function which except a `parameter` pointing which counting to be perform.

Comment: please any one check my above code and suggest how to count total number of pairs  in 1:2 or 2:1,1:1 ratio in an mlm application tree according to date(I mean day by day)